# Persist data in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

While learning Jetpack Compose, I encountered an issue where variables were getting reset upon a complete app restart (exit, close, reopen).
Is there a command that can help with this?

I tried using `remember` and `rememberSaveable`, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jetpack Compose, the remember and rememberSaveable functions are typically used to save state in the event of configuration changes such as screen rotation, as they only do not save as remember or rememberSaveable. ***Shared Preferences***, ***Database*** and ***File System*** are available for saving data even after closing the application. With these three, you can keep your data even after closing the application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

This answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: Lacks code examples or link to documentation. Very generic answer.